# Hibernate constraints on Embeddable class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Embeddable
    public static class ItemPK implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3795221679277433625L;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
        private Country country;

        @NotEmpty
        @Length(min = 3)
        private String name;
...
...
}
```

I notice that the @NotEmpty constraint is never being tested during validation. How can I enforce the validation on that field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use *@Valid* on the *ItemPK* field in *Item*? It would help if you update your example code.